# How can a function execute an action after recursing?

Tags: c++, recursion, programming-languages, computer-science

I know that recursion is a technique to call a function within the function itself.
but the below code confuses me on how it is able to do the `cout` part after the first recursion:

(This code solves the tower of hanoi puzzle)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void move_rings(int n, int src, int dest, int other); 

int main(void) 
{
    int rings;                      
    cout << "Number of Rings: ";   
    cin >> rings;
    move_rings(rings, 1, 3, 2);   

    system("PAUSE");
}

void move_rings(int rings, int source, int destination, int other)
{
     if (rings == 1)
     {
        cout << "Move from " << source << " to " << destination << endl;
     }
     else    
     {
         move_rings(rings - 1, source, other, destination);
         cout << "Move from " << source << " to " << destination << endl;
         move_rings(rings - 1, other, destination, source);  
     }
}
```

As you can see, the function `move_rings` calls itself after the `if` statement.

When I visualize this, I see a never ending loop... How is it possible for this function to do the

```
cout << "Move from " << source << " to " << destination << endl;
```

part?

The output of the program is this:

```
Move from 1 to 3
Move from 1 to 2
Move from 3 to 2
Move from 1 to 3
Move from 2 to 1
Move from 2 to 3
Move from 1 to 3
```

Comment: Are you using some IDE (e.g. Eclipse)? If so, you could use the debugger to go through the program step-by-step to better understand what is happening. Learning how to use a debugger is an essential skill, so you might as well start now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm still starting out programming though..I'll surely study it soon

Comment: @Deanie - please read  the [editing privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) page, in particular the part about "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe." In particular, remember that until you have 2,000 rep, each edit (even trivial, tag-only edits) requires votes from up to 5 other users. Please make your edits count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion can be a bit tough to grasp at first. It "clicked" for me when I thought about it like this: you have a **base case**, which is the condition that will lead the recursive function *not* to call itself anymore, and then you have the other part ("else" in your code), where the function will continue to be called. The "rings == 1" condition is your base case.

The function "move_rings" gets called with a smaller argument each time. In each subsequent call, the variable "rings" gets smaller (and therefore "moves closer" to the base case), until "rings == 1" is true, and then the function stops calling itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer (and for all other answers too)...I was able to grasp a bit of it and I know now that when the base case (or the if condition) reaches to 1, then it will print out..

Comment: ..Now, another problem arises to my head...how does the last recursive move works? (the "move_rings(rings - 1, other, destination, source);" part)...Since the rings now is equal to 1, then does the argument for the rings-1 will be equal to zero? and thus become an infinite loop?..aargh..(My teeth is clinched with these recursion stuffs)

Comment: Once the the first recursive call of "move_rings" terminates, the value of "rings" will be whatever it was when that call started. The version of "rings" used in the recursive calls is actually a "local" version that doesn't affect the value of the "rings" in the main "move_rings" call. When that local version equals 1, the first set of recursive calls ends, but then the main "move_rings" function continues with the old value of "rings." Anders Abel's answer is relevant to thinking about this.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much! I didn't realize it at first and now I think I'm seeing recursion the correct way. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Raven Make _sure_ you don't develop a gag reflex when it comes to recursion because you had some difficulty with it at first. It's an extremely helpful tool and you'll hurt yourself in the long run by this experience if it makes you not like it. Know that it's easy if you look at it the right way, and you're definitely not incapable of doing that. Recursion just usually requires a bit more thought to grasp than other concepts you run into as a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it down as a note. I'll try to further develop my skills in thinking recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Because every time `move_rings()` is called, its first argument is smaller.  Eventually, assuming a non-infinite number of rings, the function will be called on only one ring.  That's the terminating condition that causes the recursion to return.

Picture it like a binary tree structure.  Assuming a non-infinite number of nodes, you will eventually reach a leaf node beyond which there are no more.  Then you can begin traversing back up the stack along with the other code paths which found leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Because in each call to `move_rings` it passes the parameter `rings - 1`. In the end, the passed parameter will be `1` and `rings == 1` will be true.

When dealing with recursively (or any kind of reentrant) functions, it is important to understand how local variables work. Each invocation of a function has it's own incarnation of the local variables and the parameters. Envision a stack (like one of the piles in the tower of Hanoi) of bricks. Each brick contains the function parameters. When a function is called, the parameters for that one is placed on top of the stack and the function is executed, using the topmost brick's values. When the function returns, the topmost brick is discarded, returning to the values of the brick below.

Comment: This is very helpful, I think I miss the "local variable incarnation" part when visualizing recursive functions at first...But now, it's more clearer to me...Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Every time the function recurses, the it gets a ring count decremented by 1. Eventually, all branches reach the `rings==1` state and terminate. You can imagine this as a binary tree with its branches in the `else` state and its leaves in the `if` state.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` branch, the call is done with `rings - 1`. As you never increase it, eventually `rings` will be `1` and the `if` branch will be hit. As no recursion occurs in this branch, the method terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call the move_rings function, number of rings is decremented by one. Eventually, number of rings will be 1.
This code, however, could indeed produce an endless loop, because it is not well written. Number of rings is never checked to be greater than 1. So if number of rings entered in the main function is less than 1, the condition to stop recursion will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

When `move_rings` calls `move_rings`, the second call of the function starts completely fresh. It has a completely separate set of variables. It is just as if `move_rings` called any other function. It just happens to be calling "another function" that has the same name and contains the same logic.

In the second call of the function, `rings` will have a lower value, because the first call passed a smaller value for that parameter than its own. Eventually, on one of these recursive calls, the value will reach 1, and the `if` test at the beginning of the function will test true. This avoids further recursion, and that function returns. The immediately previous call of the function then resumes from where it was, just as if it had called any other function. It does its print, and then makes another recursive call where something similar happens, and then completes. And so on all the way "back up".